# Plot in two dimension

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
DensityPlot[Pro3x, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I am getting a plot that is not looking good. Can I get a plot of clarity?

Comment: What is the `Pro3x` and `Pro4x` in your question? The new edition missing the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PlotRange -> All` and set high values for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`:

```
DensityPlot[Pro4x, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"` to get

[image]

Comment: Can I label axis?

Comment: @jasmine, use `FrameLabel->{{"ylabel",None},{"xlabel" , None}}`

Comment: Any way to avoid small grids?

Comment: can you post a picture of what you mean by "small grids"?

Comment: In the graph you got, there are small lines in between two points in the y axis. That one.

Comment: try `FrameTicks -> {{Range[-4, 4, 2], {#, ""} & /@ 
    Range[-4, 4, 2]}, {Range[-4, 4, 2], {#, ""} & /@ Range[-4, 4, 2]}}`

Comment: It's working on left and down axis. But not on right and up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117410/discussion-between-jasmine-and-kglr).